# Git Bash : neither .bash_aliases nor .gitconfig read automatically

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, bash-alias

I'm setting up a new computer, and, among other things, Git with Git Bash. I copied my `.bash_aliases` and `.gitconfig` from a previous computer, but I can't get Git Bash to source them automatically.

What might I have done wrong ? How to investigate ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `.bash_aliases` is loaded from `.bashrc`. So that is required too. Mine had the following contents :

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

So I copied it over to the new computer. Then upon opening Git Bash again (on the new computer), the following was printed :

```
WARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile.

This looks like an incorrect setup.
A ~/.bash_profile that loads ~/.bashrc will be created for you.
```

And indeed now there is `.bash_profile` with :

```
# generated by Git for Windows
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

And everything works.